# Clickable Notification text in android

Tags: android, fragment, android-notifications

I have basic knowledge of android development and I'm curious to know  **if we can make any specific keyword clickable in android notification** instead of just clicking anywhere on the notification area ?
My purpose for this to show different data depending upon the click.

**e.g.** *You have successfully purchased iPhone5 and iPad mini.*
 
I want to make iPhone5 and 'iPad mini' clickable so that we can show different informations depending upon the user click.
I'm trying to use the `ClickableSpan` class but I'm still not able to perform the desired action.

Answer (score 0):

[Spannable](http://[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html][1]) brings lots of possibility to TextView, includes displaying various appearance of a Text and onClick callbak.

The normal way to make a TextView clickable is to use View.setOnClickListener. It sets a callback listener to the whole view. What if we just want to add callback to a substring of a text?

http://0xwalkingice.blogspot.in/2012/04/android-clickable-span-in-textview.html

You can use [CLickableSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html) as descried in this post

Sample code:

```
TextView myTextView = new TextView(this);
String myString = "Some text [clickable]";
int i1 = myString.indexOf("[");
int i2 = myString.indexOf("]");
myTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
myTextView.setText(myString, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
Spannable mySpannable = (Spannable)myTextView.getText();
ClickableSpan myClickableSpan = new ClickableSpan()
{
 @Override
 public void onClick(View widget) { /* do something */ }
};
mySpannable.setSpan(myClickableSpan, i1, i2 + 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

[Reference](http://adilatwork.blogspot.in/2011/07/android-how-to-make-only-part-of.html)